# Running functions parallel using Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a question about running function parallel in Python.

I have tried using multi processing to reduce time sending and receiving data from API but when I execute code below, it tend to crash my IDE.

```
def network_request_function(value)
      #this function sends requests using value.

for i in list:
      p1 = Process(target=network_request_function, args=(i,))
      p1.start()
```

Can you provide a way to fix my code?
Or are there better alternatives?

Comment: Try wrapping your process spawning loop with `if __name__ == '__main__':` so that importing your module doesn't spawn more processes - see the guidelines https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify what platform this is running on what your IDE is. Also, if all `network_request_function` is doing is making a network request and awaiting a reply which gets no further processing requiring intensive CPU, then this seems like it should be using multithreading instead of multiprocessing and a multithreading pool where the number of concurrent threads can be limited in case the length of your input list is very large and where it is simpler to get a return value from `network_request_function` that you might be interested in. **And you should not use a name, such as `list`, that happens to be the name of a built-in function or class for naming a variable.**

For example:

```py
def network_request_function(value):
    #this function sends requests using value and returns the reply
    return reply

if __name__ == '__main__': # Required if we switch to multiprocessing
    # To use multiprocessing:
    #from multiprocessing.pool import Pool as Executor
    # To use multithreading:
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Executor

    # inputs is our list of value arguments used with network_request_function:
    inputs = []; # This variable is set somewhere

    # May need to be a smaller number if we are using multiprocessing and
    # depending on the platform:
    MAX_POOL_SIZE = 200

    pool_size = min(len(inputs), MAX_POOL_SIZE)
    with Executor(pool_size) as pool:
        # Get list of all replies:
        replies = pool.map(network_request_function, inputs)
```